# how to connect sqldatasource in asp dot net with .mdf file in hosting server

Tags: asp.net

I am new in asp net .

I have created a website in asp dot net i want it to be connect through mdf file(tradingcalls.mdf) to my website .

I want it to connect the mdf file contain in the App_Data folder in my hosting server

I am using this connection string for my database to be connect

I am getting error when i am using this string

The connection name 'ConnectionString' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.

You can check this link by checking this you would understand the error ,

http://www.mcxnsecalls.com/insert-calls.aspx

Can anyone help me from getting out of this

There would be a great appreciation if someine could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have an error in the way you put the connection string in your web.config.
Please post the relevant section of the web.config in here.
The connection string should have the name "ConnectionString" like in the example below:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="yourConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Update: as I said above, looking at your web.config I can see that you have to change the name of your connection string from "trdagingcallsConnectionString2" to "ConnectionString"

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="trdagingcallsConnectionString2" connectionString ="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|trdagingcalls.mdf;Database=trdagingcalls; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode ="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Ok, I'll do that next time. However I wanted to add the he should put the name ConnectionString as he might have a different one.

Comment: change the name of your connection string from "trdagingcallsConnectionString2" to "ConnectionString"

Comment: thanks but i am getting another error the error is A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: glad the first error was solved. This seems to be some configuration of Sql Server that needs to be changed, or the Connection string that is incorrect. Can you connect to the server instance in any other way? is it local or already remote in your host? You are also trying to access it without username and password with integrated security and this might not be allowed in an hosting environment. Maybe it's best to post another question in stackoverflow to get further help.